# Javascript Filevalidation always return false

Tags: javascript, file, validation

I have a function that is part of a fileupload, however when i try to validate the files through an array, wether i use an "accepted" file or a "wrong" file, i get the same end result which is the alert message on the return false statement of the code.

can someone spot an error here ? there are no syntax errors in the function.

```
handleFiles = function (files,e){
var rand = Math.floor((Math.random()*100000)+3);

for(var i=0, file; file = files[i]; i++) {

var fileType = new Array("psd","ai","eps","svg","png","doc","docx","jpg","jpeg","pptx","ppt","gif");
var file_extension = file.name.split('.').pop().toLowerCase();

if (parseInt(file.size / 1024) > 204800) {  
    alert("Filen er \""+file.name+"\" for stor");
    return false;   
}
    if (fileType[i]==file_extension)
    {
        var src = '/printuploads/upload.png'

        var template = '<div class="eachImage" id="'+rand+'">';
        template += '<span class="preview" id="'+rand+'"><img src="'+src+'"><span class="overlay"><span class="updone"></span></span>';
        template += '</span>'
        template += '<div class="progress" id="'+rand+'"><span></span></div>';  

        if($("#dropbox .eachImage").html() == null)
        $("#dropbox").html(template);
        else
        $("#dropbox").append(template);

        upload(file,rand);
        return true;
    }
    alert("Forkert filformat");
    return false;
}
};
```

Comment: `if (fileType[i]==file_extension)` -- This is probably the issue. You're expecting the nth file in the `files` array to have the nth extension in your  `fileType` array.

Comment: Also, you should move the definition of the `fileType` array outside the loop. It's not an error, but it unnecessarily creates the same array over and over again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your validation to check if the file extension is supported is incorrect:

```
fileType[i]==file_extension
```

Here, `i` is the index of file, not the extension. So every file extension is being compared with "psd".

Instead it should be checking if the extension is available in the array `file_extension`. You can do that using `Array#some` method:

```
fileType.some(t => t == file_extension)
```

Or, you can simply check that the extension belongs to the array using `indexOf`:

```
fileType.indexOf(file_extension) >= 0
```

Here's a working snippet, you can check the logged value in the console:

```js
var handleFiles = function(files, e) {
  var rand = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100000) + 3);

  for (var i = 0, file; file = files[i]; i++) {

    var fileType = new Array("psd", "ai", "eps", "svg", "png", "doc", "docx", "jpg", "jpeg", "pptx", "ppt", "gif");
    var file_extension = file.name.split('.').pop().toLowerCase();

    if (parseInt(file.size / 1024) > 204800) {
      alert("Filen er \"" + file.name + "\" for stor");
      return false;
    }
    
    if (fileType.some(t => t == file_extension)) {
      console.log("Extension matches");
      var src = '/printuploads/upload.png'

      var template = '<div class="eachImage" id="' + rand + '">';
      template += '<span class="preview" id="' + rand + '"><img src="' + src + '"><span class="overlay"><span class="updone"></span></span>';
      template += '</span>'
      template += '<div class="progress" id="' + rand + '"><span></span></div>';

      if ($("#dropbox .eachImage").html() == null)
        $("#dropbox").html(template);
      else
        $("#dropbox").append(template);

      upload(file, rand);
      return true;
    }
    alert("Forkert filformat");
    return false;
  }
};

function upload() {};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type ="file" onchange="handleFiles(this.files, event);">
```